# How do i make all the ' symbols into " while still detecting the variables in PHP?

Tags: php

So I have this peice of code, the function is not relavant for the question
Samplefunction("fileDirectory", 23, "**{ 'title': '.$PageTitle', 'url': '/.$PageTitle/' },**");

In the row in bold, the line: "**{ 'title': '.$PageTitle', 'url': '/.$PageTitle/' },**" is a good and working line. however since this is a sting in a function, currently the ' symbols have to be ".

If i writ the line like so:
'**{ "title": ".$PageTitle", "url": "/.$PageTitle/" },**');

The string will be ok but the variables will be undetected.

I need the string within to a " and not a ' but i also need the variables to be detected.
Any suggestions on how to do this?
Best Regards,
AT

My complete code:

```
$filedirectory = "/sample/file/directoy";


$PageTitle = "shop";
function textinjector($file, $linerNumber, $injText ) {

$content = file($file); //Read the file into an array. Line number => line content
foreach($content as $lineNumber => &$lineContent) { //Loop through the array (the "lines")
    if($lineNumber == $linerNumber) { //Remember we start at line 0.
        $lineContent .= $injText . PHP_EOL; //Modify the line. (We're adding another line by using PHP_EOL)

    } 
}

$allContent = implode("", $content); //Put the array back into one string
file_put_contents($file, $allContent); //Overwrite the file with the new content
echo "$injText was injected to $file at line number $lineNumber";
}

// insertTextAtLineNumber("$filedirectory", 20, "import $pagetitlecaps from './$PageTitle/index';");
textinjector("$filedirectory", 23, '{ "title": ".$PageTitle", "url": "/.$PageTitle/" },'); // inject text into the menu area 
?>
```

Comment: You should post more of your code. Probably the body of the function would make some difference on the best solution. Otherwise you could try something like this

Samplefunction("fileDirectory", 23, json_encode(array('title'=>$pageTitle', 'url' => '$PageTitle'))

Comment: Are you trying to create JSON? Then don't do so by hand. Create an array, then `json_encode` it. Alternatively, instead of changing the quotes, *escape* problematic quotes (e.g. `"{\"title\"...}"`). Yet alternatively, *concatenate* your strings instead of relying on variable interpolation.

Comment: the json is a huge file. just trying to inject one line into it wich i have succeeded in doing. just need to make the ' into a ".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the way you generate the string by breaking the it up in to the separate parts (static and dynamic) and concatenating the parts together with `.`

```
textinjector($filedirectory, 23, '{ "title": ".' . $PageTitle . '", "url": "/.' . $PageTitle . '/" },');
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much

Comment: another question, if im trying to do the exact opisite i.e.   textinjector("/var/www/html/uploadTest/test2.php", 26,  "'test' => array($this, 'getTestData'),"); for instence the "$this" variable is is a variable that once injected needs to stay $this  and not be detected as a variabel. any sujestions to how i do that?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you mean